# vue.js で vue-simple-suggest を使用したサジェスト（候補表示）について質問です

Tags: javascript, vue.js

環境:

- OS: windows10
- ブラウザ: chrome
- 言語：javascript
- フレームワーク:vue.js,vue-simple-sugges

vue-simple-suggest というパッケージを使って下図のような駅名候補リストを表示する機能を作成しています。
そこで以下の質問があります。

1. 下図①でIME確定前に vue-simple-sugges が下図③の候補リストを表示してしまいますが、IME確定後に変更することは可能でしょうか？
2. 下図②のように以前に入力した文字が勝手に表示されてしまうのですが制御する方法はないのでしょうか？ input タグに value="", autocomplete="off" を追加しましたが表示され続けます。(②は、未入力でアクティブになった時に表示される過去の入力履歴と、IME確定前のIME予測で表示されるパターンがあるように思います）

[image: サジェストされた時のキャプチャ]

以上、宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: ２のほうはIMEの予測入力の可能性はないですか？

Comment: IMEの予測入力かもしれません。ですが、(1) のエリアがアクティブ（入力可能な状態）になった瞬間に過去に入力したと思われる履歴が数件、表示され、その後,IME入力していると図の状態となってしまいます。私は同じ仕組みで表示されているのかと思っていました。。。IME、履歴ともに表示したくないのですが、対応方法はないのでしょうか？

Comment: 履歴とIME確定前とIMEの三つということですか？であれば質問も編集して追記しておいてください。